# Fast function to check if url exists PHP

Tags: php, http-headers

I used @file_get_contents and get_headers, both are slow even if the URL is below 1ko, tried to use cURL but it isn't supported by the server. Is there any fast fucntion to use instead ?

Comment: No idea what you mean by "a URL exists" and "URL is below 1ko" mean, but if you want to test if a request to a URL results in some error or not, then you simply have to make a HEAD request, no way around that. `get_headers()` is the most efficient way for making a HEAD request.

Comment: Url exists means  (not 404)  ?? & put your code what you have tried using file_get_contents and get_headers.

Comment: @arkascha
I mean by "URL exists" (not 404) a valid url ... and URL below 1ko .. I mean the page size, I already tried to use get_headers() but it's slowing the page load time, because it is handling more than 50 url

Comment: Note that a URL "exists" regardless if whether some object or page is returned when making a request to it. The URL itself is only an address, it exists the moment you name it. What you are actually looking for is the set of results you get back that you consider indicating something "non existent". But that always refers to the _result of a request_, not to the URL.

Comment: About the speed of testing URLs by means of a HEAD request: as said before: there is little you can do here, a HEAD request is as effective as it can get. You _could_ try to implement that request yourself, using raw socket operations. But you would end up doing exactly what `get_headers()` does, so you would gain nothing. Note that the performance of a request to some external server depends more on that server and your network environment, less on your local system.

Answer (score 1):

using the method suggested by @arkascha you could do something like this:

```
$url='http://stackoverflow.com';
$options=array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method'        =>  'HEAD',
        'User-Agent'    =>  $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
    )
);
stream_context_get_default( $options );
$headers=get_headers( $url, 1 );
echo $headers[0];
```

It seems fairly quick and you could further parse the response to find if the status is 200 or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

[Frank Koehl](http://hotkoehls.com/) did a neat little function to do just that and return the url’s http status.

[http status code function](http://frankkoehl.com/2009/09/http-status-code-curl-php/)

```
/**
 * @author  Frank Koehl
 * @src    http://frankkoehl.com/2009/09/http-status-code-curl-php/
 */
function get_status($url)
{
    // must set $url first. Duh...
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    // do your curl thing here
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $http_status;
}
```

Comment: O.P. did say they had no curl support.